# Limit of a power series in $\beta$ multiplied by $(1 - \beta)$

Tags: limits, power-series, limsup-and-liminf, divergent-series, analyticity

Suppose that you are given a bounded sequence of real numbers $|w_k| \le W$.

What should be the limit $\lim_{\beta \rightarrow 1^-}\  (1 - \beta) \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \beta^k w_k$?

To see that the limit exists, consider that the function $v(\beta) = (1 - \beta) \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \beta^k w_k$ is analytic and that $|v(\beta)| \le (1 - \beta) \sum_{k = 0}^\infty W \beta^k \le W$ so it is bounded near $\beta = 1$ and admits a limit.

I guess that is should be something like $\limsup_n \frac1n \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} w_k$ but I failed to prove it.

Edit: The limit could not exist, see the answer of metamorphy.
I'm still interested if the relation
$$ \limsup_{\beta \rightarrow 1^-} \ (1 - \beta) \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \beta^k w_k = \limsup_n \frac1n \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} w_k$$
holds or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your guess of the limit, if everything converges nicely (as  power series with bounded coefficients do for $|\beta|< 1$) then

$$ (1-\beta)\sum_{k=0}^\infty w_k\beta^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (w_k-w_{k-1})\beta^k, \quad (|\beta| < 1), $$
after the mild abuse of notation $w_{-1}:=0$. Thus if the limit does exist, it has to be the Abel sum of the backward differences $\Delta w_k:= w_{k}-w_{k-1}$. c.f. [definition of Abel summation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Abel_summation).

In particular, if I understand it correctly, metamorphy's example is a variant of the usual example of how some generalised summation methods are affected by dilution of the summands(i.e. padding the sequence $\Delta w_k$ with a bunch of zeros so that their sum $w_k$ stays constant for extended stretches of $k$). See for instance [this paper I found on a google search](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.0346.pdf) and of course in [the book by Hardy, "Divergent Series" (page 59)](https://archive.org/details/DivergentSeries/page/n75). Also, the divergence result of metamorphy is proven on [page 93](https://archive.org/details/DivergentSeries/page/n93) with slightly more generality (I'll quote the proof at the end.)

In any case, 
your guess is like saying that the limit is equal to the Cesàro sum of $\Delta w_k$. Although Cesàro and Abel sums agree when defined, there are times when Cesàro doesn't exist but Abel does. But from [Theorem 92 of Divergent Series](https://archive.org/details/DivergentSeries/page/n93), your guess is true (with lim and not just limsup) the moment the LHS exists, since $\Delta w_k$ are bounded. That is, we have

> Suppose $\Delta w_k $ is bounded. Then these two limits exist are equal as long as either one exists:
>   $$ \lim_{\beta \rightarrow 1^{-}}(1-\beta) \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \beta^{k} w_{k}=\lim _{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} w_{k}$$

(Boundedness is essential. For instance, $\Delta w_k = (-1)^k(k+1)$ has Abel sum $1/4$ but is not Cesàro summable, and also the limsup isn't equal to the Abel sum, since the average of the partial summands alternate between $ k/(2k-1) \approx 1/2$ and $0$. )

For example, the "undiluted" version of metamorphy's example (up to a change in $\Delta w_0$ and a scaling) is the Cesàro summable $ \Delta w_k $ given by
$$ \Delta w_k = (-1)^{k}, \quad w_k = \frac{(-1)^k+1}2,$$

and the RHS of the claimed identity is $\lim _{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} w_{k} = 1/2$. The LHS is
$$\lim_{\beta\uparrow 1}(1-\beta)\sum_{k=0}^\infty \beta^{2k} = \lim_{\beta\uparrow 1}\frac{1-\beta}{1-\beta^2}= \lim_{\beta\uparrow 1} \frac{1}{1+\beta} =\frac12,$$
as predicted.

Finally, I wanted to quote wholesale the beautiful proof of Hardy from [page 93](https://archive.org/details/DivergentSeries/page/n93); I think more people should read it. It proves that Abel summability can be destroyed by dilution of series (which is a stronger result than the analogous result for Cesàro summability.)

> On the other hand, if $a>1,$ then
>   $$ F(x)=x-x^{a}+x^{a^{2}}-x^{a^{2}}+\dots$$
>   does not tend to a limit when $x \rightarrow 1$ . To see this, we observe that $F(x)$ satisfies
>   the functional equation
>   $$F(x)+F\left(x^{a}\right)=x$$
>   and that $$ \Phi(x)=\sum \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n !\left(1+a^{n}\right)}\left(\log \frac{1}{x}\right)^{n}$$ 
>   is another solution. Hence $\Psi(x)=F(x)-\Phi(x)$ satisfies $\Psi(x)=-\Psi\left(x^{a}\right),$ and is
>   therefore a periodic function of $\log \log (1 / x)$ with period $2 \log a .$ since it is plainly not constant, it oscillates between finite limits of indetermination when $x \rightarrow 1,\log (1 / x) \rightarrow 0, \log \log (1 / x) \rightarrow-\infty .$ But $\Phi(x) \rightarrow \frac{1}{2},$ and therefore $F(x)$ oscillates.
>
> It follows that $1-1+1-\ldots$ is not summable $(A, \lambda)$ when $\lambda_{n}=a^{n}(a>1)$.

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can't prove it already because of expected behaviour of the answer w.r.t. $w_k\mapsto-w_k$. Further, your "... and admits a limit" is left unjustified, and in fact **the limit can fail to exist**.

Here is a counterexample, maybe not the simplest but I think interesting:
$$w_k=\begin{cases}0,&k=0\\\color{blue}{(-1)^{\lfloor\log_2 k\rfloor}},&k>0\end{cases}$$
with $w(\beta):=(1-\beta)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}w_k\beta^k=\beta+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\beta^{2^n}$.
[image: Plots of the function w]
To analyse $\beta\to 1^{-}$, let's consider $W(x)=w(e^{-x})$ for $x>0$, and [use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform#Cahen%E2%80%93Mellin_integral)
$$e^{-y}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\Gamma(s)y^{-s}\,ds$$
where $y,c>0$ are arbitrary. We get
$$W(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{\Gamma(s)}{x^s}\frac{2^s-1}{2^s+1}\,ds=A(x)+B(x),$$
where $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ come from residues at $s=-n$ and $s=\pm(2n+1)\pi i/\ln 2$:
$$A(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{2^n-1}{2^n+1}\frac{x^n}{n!},\\ B(x)=\frac{4}{\ln 2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Re\left[e^{-(2n+1)\pi i\log_2 x}\Gamma\Big(\frac{2n+1}{\ln 2}\pi i\Big)\right].$$
While $A(x)\to 0$ with $x\to 0$, $B(x)$ keeps oscillating, with no convergence to anything.

---

Regarding the "Edit": **nope**. The same counterexample works. Namely,
$$|B(x)|\leqslant\frac{4}{\ln 2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left|\Gamma\Big(\frac{2n+1}{\ln 2}\pi i\Big)\right|<0.0055$$
while $\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}w_k=\frac{1}{3}$ (considering the subsequence with $n=2^{2k+1}$).

Comment: I don't get the same sum with the specified $w_k$, since grouping the indices $k$ for which $\lfloor \log_2 k \rfloor = s$ (i.e. $2^s \le k < 2^{s+1}$) i get that the sum of $\sum_{k = 2^s}^{2^{s+1}} (-1)^s \beta^k = (-1)^s \beta^{2^s} \frac{1 - \beta^{2^s}}{1 - \beta}$ so that the original sum $w(\beta) = \sum_{s = 0}^\infty (-1)^s \beta^{2^s} (1 - \beta^{2^s})$.

Am I missing something? In any case thanks for the example.

Comment: You get $\sum_{k=2^s}^{\color{red}{2^{s+1}-1}}\ldots$ but your *final* result is correct, and it's the same as mine (just split $\beta^{2^s}(1-\beta^{2^s})=\beta^{2^s}-\beta^{2^{s+1}}$ and regroup; one can even proceed with yours).