Let lacunary power series $f_s(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n^{s} x^{a_n}$, does $\lim_{x\to1}(1-x)f_s(x)$ exist?
As is known to all, if $a_n=n$ and $s=0$, then the power series $$f_s(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n^{s} x^{a_n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n}=\frac{1}{1-x},\; 0<x<1.$$
It follows that $\lim_{x\to1}(1-x)f_s(x)=1$.
For any integer $n\geq 0$, $n$ can be expanded into binary format $$n=c_0+c_12+c_22^2+\cdots+c_k2^k,$$
for some $k\geq0$, $c_j\in\{0,1\}$, $0\leq j\leq k$. Let $s=1-\log2/\log4=1/2$ and
$$a_n:=c_0+c_14+c_24^2+\cdots+c_k4^k,\;n\geq0.$$
Let the lacunary power series $f_{1/2}(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n^{1/2} x^{a_n}$. Does $\lim_{x\to1}(1-x)f_{1/2}(x)$ exist ?

The answer is negative; in fact $(1-x)f_{1/2}(x)$ oscillates as $x\to 1^-$. The (zeta-style) approach below computes explicitly the Fourier expansion of the oscillating part, as a function of $\log(-\log x)$.

The series $A(s):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{-s}$ converges (absolutely) for $s\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\Re s>1/2$, and defines an analytic function there. Now let $A_\pm(s):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}a_n^{-s}$; since $a_{2n}=4a_n$ and $a_{2n+1}=4a_n+1$, we get
\begin{gather}
A_\pm(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{-s}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{2n}^{-s}=(1-2^{1-2s})A(s);
\\
A_\pm(s)=1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\big((4a_n)^{-s}-(4a_n+1)^{-s}\big).
\end{gather}
The last series converges for $\Re s>-1/2$, and defines the analytic continuation of $A_\pm(s)$ there.
Thus, we have $A(s)$ analytically continued onto $\Re s>-1/2$, with simple poles at
$$
s=\frac12+s_m,\quad s_m:=\frac{m\pi i}{\log2},\quad m\in\mathbb{Z}
$$
if $A_\pm(1/2+s_m)\neq 0$, which can be verified numerically for a few values of $m$.

Next, we need an estimate of $|A_\pm(\sigma+i\tau)|$ as $|\tau|\to\infty$, with $\sigma>-1/2$ fixed. Write
$$
a^{-\sigma-i\tau}-(a+1)^{-\sigma-i\tau}=a^{-\sigma}\big(a^{-i\tau}-(a+1)^{-i\tau}\big)+(a+1)^{-i\tau}(a^{-\sigma}-(a+1)^{-\sigma})
$$
(with $a>0$). Since
$$
|a^{-i\tau}-(a+1)^{-i\tau}|=2\left|\sin\left(\frac\tau2\log\frac{a+1}a\right)\right|\leqslant\frac{|\tau|}a
$$
and (one can obtain from Bernoulli's inequality that)
$$
|a^{-\sigma}-(a+1)^{-\sigma}|\leqslant|\sigma|a^{-1-\sigma},
$$
we obtain
$$
\left|a^{-\sigma-i\tau}-(a+1)^{-\sigma-i\tau}\right|\leqslant(|\tau|+|\sigma|)a^{-1-\sigma}.\tag{*}\label{estimate}
$$
If we put $a=4a_n$ and sum over $n$, we get a crude estimate $|A_\pm(\sigma+i\tau)|=O(|\tau|)$.

Coming back to $f_{1/2}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{1/2}x^{a_n}$, we use the Cahen–Mellin integral
$$
e^{-t}=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty}\Gamma(s)t^{-s}\,ds\qquad(t,\sigma>0)
$$
with $\color{blue}{\sigma>1}$ to justify the interchange of $\sum$ and $\int$ below:
\begin{align}
f_{1/2}(e^{-t})&=\frac1{2\pi i}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{1/2}\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty}\Gamma(s)(a_n t)^{-s}\,ds
\\&=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty}\Gamma(s)A(s-1/2)t^{-s}\,ds
\\&=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty}\frac{\Gamma(s)A_\pm(s-1/2)t^{-s}}{1-4^{1-s}}\,ds.
\end{align}
The crude estimate above shows that, as $|\Im s|\to\infty$, the exponential decay of $|\Gamma(s)|$ "outperforms" the (possible) growth of $|A_\pm(s-1/2)|$. This allows us to shift the line of integration to $\color{blue}{0<\sigma<1}$, using the residue theorem:
\begin{align}
f_{1/2}(e^{-t})&=\frac1{2t\log2}\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\Gamma(1+s_m)A_\pm(1/2+s_m)t^{-s_m}
\\&+\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty}\frac{\Gamma(s)A_\pm(s-1/2)t^{-s}}{1-4^{1-s}}\,ds.
\end{align}
The integral is now $O(t^{-\sigma})$ as $t\to 0^+$, and we can take $\sigma$ arbitrarily close to $0$.
And the sum is the (non-constant) Fourier expansion announced at the beginning.

ADDENDUM on computation of $A_m:=A_\pm\left(\frac12+\frac{m\pi i}{\log2}\right)$ (and $A_\pm(s)$ in general). Let
$$
A_\pm(s)=S_N(s)+R_N(s),\qquad R_N(s):=\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\big((4a_n)^{-s}-(4a_n+1)^{-s}\big).
$$
The estimate \eqref{estimate} above, and the inequality $4a_n\geqslant n^2$, imply
$$
\big|R_N(\sigma+i\tau)\big|\leqslant(|\tau|+|\sigma|)\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty n^{-2-2\sigma}\leqslant\frac{|\tau|+|\sigma|}{1+2\sigma}N^{-1-2\sigma}.
$$
This estimate at $N=2$ is (already) sufficient to prove that $\color{blue}{A_1\neq 0}$.

To accelerate the convergence for more efficient computations, consider
$$
\Sigma_k(s):=S_{2^k-1}(s),\qquad\Delta_k(s):=R_{2^k-1}(s).
$$
It appears that $\Delta_k(s)$ has an asymptotic expansion of the form
$$
\Delta_k(s)\asymp\sum_{j=0}^{(\infty)} c_j(s)2^{-(2j+2s+1)k}.\qquad(k\to\infty)
$$
This eventually leads to the following "recipe".
Let $\sum_{j=0}^r p_{r,j} x^j:=\prod_{j=0}^{r-1}(4^j x-1)$ for a (small) positive integer $r$, and define
$$
\Sigma_k^{(r)}(s)=\frac{\sum_{j=0}^r 2^{(2s+1)j}p_{r,j}\Sigma_{k+j}(s)}{\sum_{j=0}^r 2^{(2s+1)j}p_{r,j}}.
$$
Then $\Sigma_k^{(r)}(s)$ is computed in roughly the same time as $\Sigma_{k+r}(s)$ (if the values are computed in sequence with increasing $k$) but converges to $A_\pm(s)$ much faster. This way, I've got the following values.



$m$
$\approx\Re A_m$
$\approx\Im A_m$




$0$
$\phantom{-}0.9301188714777068256428634$
$\phantom{-}0$


$1$
$\phantom{-}0.6530947000949628569271101$
$-0.4875373269525809327441595$


$2$
$\phantom{-}0.1502485249871372257970461$
$-0.4820952084817942842557168$


$3$
$-0.0092994993442554458938163$
$-0.0963080518133936172598479$


$4$
$\phantom{-}0.2783414309554035350627076$
$\phantom{-}0.1200023391019127895989171$


$5$
$\phantom{-}0.5592044887794212271016653$
$-0.1168455562119756445211653$




Hello @metamorphy
. Thank you for your reply. Your answer gave me a lot of inspiration, but I still couldn't read it too well. Could you please clarify the details more? If there are any tutorials or theories that can help understand, please advise.

For example, you said the oscillating part of
$(1-x)f(x)$ as a function of $\log(-\log x)$. But $(1-x)f(x),;(x\to 1^{-})$ is
bounded. The simple calculation is as follows.

By using your previous conclusion https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3276562, we get the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to1^{-}}(1-x)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}4^{n} x^{4^n}=1/\ln 4.;;;(1)
$$
Let $\Omega_n={c_0+c_14+c_24^2+\cdots+c_n4^n:c_i\in{0,1}, 0\leq i\leq n}$ for $n\geq 0$. Then
$$f_s(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n^{s} x^{a_n}=\sum_{a\in\Omega_0} a^{s} x^{a}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{a\in\Omega_n\setminus\Omega_{n-1}} a^{s} x^{a},; 0<x<1.$$
Note that $2^{n}(4^{n})^{s}x^{2\times4^n}\leq\sum_{a\in\Omega_n\setminus\Omega_{n-1}} a^{s} x^{a}\leq 2^{n}(2\times4^{n})^{s}x^{4^n}$ and $s=1/2$.

Hence
$$h(x):=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}4^n (x^2)^{4^n}\leq f_{\frac12}(x)\leq1+\sqrt{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}4^n x^{4^n}=:g(x),; 0<x<1.$$
By (1), we have $h(x)\sim\frac1{1-x^2}\sim \frac{1}{2(1-x)}$ and $g(x)\sim\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1-x}$ as $x\to 1^{-}$. This implies
$$\frac12\leq(1-x)f(x)\geq \sqrt{2};;(x\to 1^{-}).$$

Dear @metamorphy, thank you. I understand this question now. But I have another question in your proof: why the sum
$$
\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\Gamma(1+s_m)A_\pm(1/2+s_m)t^{-s_m}
$$
is the (non-constant) Fourier expansion? As you mentioned above, this is equivalent to
$A_\pm(1/2+s_m)\neq 0$ for some $m\neq 0$. You say it can be verified numerically for a few values of $m$, I want to know how to prove it theoretically or numerically?

@user130405: See the updated answer.

A real-analysis way following these lines, with the lower/upper limits computed.
Let's extend $a_n$ to non-integers first. Define $\lambda:\mathbb{R}_{\geqslant0}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geqslant0}$ by
$$
\lambda\left(\sum_{n\in\Omega}2^n\right)=\sum_{n\in\Omega}4^n
$$
for any $\Omega\subset\mathbb{Z}$ with $\sup\Omega<\infty$ and $\inf(\mathbb{Z}\setminus\Omega)=-\infty$.
Then, following the answer linked above, we find:
$$
\color{blue}{\lim_{m\to\infty}4^{t-m}f_{1/2}(e^{-4^{t-m}})=4^t F(4^t),}
$$
where $F(x)=\int_0^\infty\lambda(y)^{1/2}e^{-x\lambda(y)}\,dy$ for $x>0$.
Again, $t\mapsto 4^t F(4^t)$ is a $1$-periodic function. To compute its minimum/maximum, we need a quick enough computation of $F$ (and, perhaps, its derivative). The idea I have is to use
$$
F(x)=-\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\int_x^\infty\frac{G'(y)}{\sqrt{y-x}}\,dy,
$$
where $G(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x\lambda(y)}\,dy$ has a nice infinite-product expansion:
$$
G(x)=\prod_{n=0}^\infty(1+e^{-4^n x})\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1+e^{-4^{-n}x}}2.
$$
After some simplifications, I wrote the following PARI/GP script:
foo(x) = 2^x * prodinf(n=0, exp(-4^(x+n)), 1) * prodinf(n=1, expm1(-4^(x-n))/2, 1);
goo1(n,x) = { my(y=4^(x+n), z=exp(-y)); return(z*y/(1+z)) };
goo2(n,x) = { my(y=4^(x+n), z=exp(-y)); return(z*(y/(1+z))^2) };
goo0(n,x) = { my(y=4^(-x-n)); return(y/sqrt(1-y)) };
foo1(x) = suminf(n=0, goo1(n,x)) + suminf(n=1, goo1(-n,x));
foo2(x) = suminf(n=0, goo2(n,x)) + suminf(n=1, goo2(-n,x));
foo0(x) = suminf(n=0, goo0(n,x));
ker1(x) = foo(x)*foo1(x);
ker2(x) = { my(y=foo1(x)); return(foo(x)*(y*(3-2*y)-2*foo2(x))) };
objfun(x) = intnum(t=[0,-1/2], 1, foo0(t)*ker1(x+t));
objder(x) = intnum(t=[0,-1/2], 1, foo0(t)*ker2(x+t));
objmin = 2*log(2)/sqrt(Pi) * objfun(solve(x=0.8,0.9,objder(x)));
objmax = 2*log(2)/sqrt(Pi) * objfun(solve(x=0.3,0.4,objder(x)));

that computes the lower limit as objmin and the upper limit as objmax:
\begin{align}
\liminf_{x\to 1^-}\ (1-x)f_{1/2}(x) &= 0.66586394843939004821628799734260998\cdots
\\
\limsup_{x\to 1^-}\ (1-x)f_{1/2}(x) &= 0.67601923344314595333773524756892407\cdots
\end{align}
(compare with the "mean value" $A_0/(2\log2)\approx0.670938941659\cdots$).
